# Servlet Null Pointer exception on page load before submit

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

my servlet below is firing a null pointer exception, but the server console is not detailing where the exception is firing from. Also the page for which the form linked to the servlet is on doesn't load and just displays a HTTP Status 500 error about the null pointer exception. Below i have copied my servlet and database connection code but can really see where the error would originate from?

Can someone take a look at my code and see if there is any immediate problem?

My Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "DateSearchServlet", urlPatterns = {"/Search"})
public class DateSearchServlet {

DatabaseConnector dataManager;
boolean dbOK = false;
HomeList homes = new HomeList();

public void init() {
    dataManager = new DatabaseConnector();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String dateFrom = request.getParameter("from");
    String dateTo = request.getParameter("to");

    if (dateFrom == null || dateTo == null) {
        dbOK = false;
    } else {
        dbOK = true;
    }//end if

    if (dbOK) {
        homes = dataManager.getPropertiesSearch(dateFrom, dateTo);
        request.setAttribute("homeList", homes);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("bookings.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        System.out.println("DBNOTOK");
        //will add error messages etc...
    }
}
}
```

JSP page:

```
<div class="dateSearch">
   <form name="dateSearch" action="DateSearchServlet" method="post">
   <label for="from">Date From</label>
   <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
   <label for="to">Date To</label>
   <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit">
   </form>
</div>
<h2>List of Properties</h2>
<%
    HomeList homes = (HomeList)request.getAttribute("homeList");
%>
```

xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DateSearchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DB.DateSearchServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DateSearchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Database search method:

```
    public HomeList getPropertiesSearch(String from, String to) {
    HomeList homes = new HomeList();//UserBean object to hold the user data
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = createConnection(conn);//set up the connection to the datbase

    //if connection is sucessful, create empty ResultSet and PreparedStatement
    if (conn != null) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            String strQuery =
                    "SELECT homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft, "
                    + "listagg(features.feature_name, '\\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, home_type.type_name\n"
                    + "FROM homes "
                    + "INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.home_id <> homes.home_id"
                    + "INNER JOIN home_feature ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id"
                    + "INNER JOIN home_type ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code"
                    + "INNER JOIN features ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id"
                    + "WHERE bookings.booking_end < date '?'"
                    + "OR bookings.booking_start > date '?'"
                    + "GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name";

            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);//prepare the statement
            preparedStatement.setString(1, to);//insert password into query
            preparedStatement.setString(2, from);//insert password into query
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();//execute the query and store this into a ResultSet

            homes = new HomeList(rs);
        }//end try
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeConnection(conn);//call close connection the close the database connection
        }//end finally
    }//end if

    conn = closeConnection(conn);

    return homes;
}
```

Thanks if anyone can point me in the right directions

StackTrace:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.bookings_jsp._jspService(bookings_jsp.java:191)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: How do you know there is a NPE? Does it say where in the error message?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Does `closeConnection()` test whether the passed `conn` is null, or mind if it already closed? Is `bookings.jsp` a valid *relative* path - if not `getRequestDispatcher` might return null and `.forward` would get NPE, but I don't think that's it. Does `bookings_jsp.java` relate to the servlet or DB code - I assume the latter - and if so which is line 191?

Answer (score 0):

when are you calling the init() method? most likely it is never called and you got a NPE because `dataManager` is null at this line:

```
 homes = dataManager.getPropertiesSearch(dateFrom, dateTo);
```

Comment: It's a servlet, so `init()` is invoked automatically when the instance is loaded - you don't call it explicitly.